# can we pass an attribute as an argument in python 3.4?

Tags: function, attributes, web-scraping, parameter-passing, python-3.4

I have two questions :

1) I wonder if (and how) we can pass an attribue (a tag) as an argument to make a check on this tag, it's what am trying below.

2) If we can't, or if I try to pass a tag that is a nonsense, it seems that it doesn't generate an AttributeError since it doesn't print it, am I doing something wrong ?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getTitle(url,tag):
    try:
        html = urlopen(url)

    except HTTPError as e:
         print("wrong url")
         print(e)
         return None
    except URLError as j:
         print ("dead server")
         print(j)
         return None

    try:
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")
        title = bsObj.patate
        print("testobject")
        print(title)

    except AttributeError as AE:
        print("AttributeError is : ")
        print(AE)
        return(None)
    return title


title = getTitle("http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html", "h1")

if title == None:
    print ("titre non trouvé")
else:
    print(title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue: the function `getTitle`, given an argument "someTag", should return `bsObj.someTag`.
In other words, you want to access the attribute of a class (`bsObj`) given the attribute name as a string ("someTag").

Python has the function [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to do just that:

```
tag="h1"
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")
retrieveTag=getattr(bsObj,tag)                    #same as bsObj.h1
```

In this case if there is no attribute "tag", `getattr` returns `None`, so you don't need to catch `AttributeError`.

You could also defined a default return value with something like:

```
retrieveTag=getattr(bsObj,tag,"tag not found")
```